# Template.beforeDestroy hook Spacebars/Meteor

Tags: meteor, spacebars

Is there any way to get a hook that fires before the template is removed from the DOM?

I have a memory leak due to not being able to destroy my mCustomScrollbars before the DOM elements are destroyed.

Comment: Why can't you destroy it in the destroy callback? Attach a reference to your `mCustomScrollbars` in the template instance, and in the destroy callback you can use `this` to reference to your template instance.

Comment: I was doing that, but it turns out that $(selector).mCustomScrollbar("destroy") only works when the element is still in the DOM. If you attempt to use it on a selector that's already been removed it causes a memory leak. I posted something about it on [github](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues/169) (scroll down to see the memory leak).

Comment: Sorry, that was not what I meant. In the created callback, do something like `this.mCustomScrollbars = something-that-gives-you-a-reference-to-what-you-need`, and in the destroyed callback, use `this.mCustomScrollbars` to do your clean up. But Jeremy S.s solution may be better.

Comment: Ohh wow, yeah that's simple, I should have just done that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now no.

But this is being introduced in 0.8.2 which should be released any day. Look under the release notes for it [> here <](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#blaze) and there are hooks for `insertElement`, `removeElement` and `moveElement` under the 'Blaze' section.

Also looks like the terminology may be in flux until 1.0.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! I'll just wait a couple days for the release... 0.8.2 is also the update that will make it trivial to do DOM animations as well correct?

Comment: That is the primary purpose of it (as opposed to addressing memory leaks, which may be a valuable side effect). Hopefully some documentation and examples will be included as well.